# Proper test to check for convergence/divergence of $Z_n = (1+2i)^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

First, I would like to know if I did this correctly

$$Z_n = (1+2i)^n$$
$$(z)^n = r^n(\cos(n\theta)+i\sin(n\theta))$$
$$r = \sqrt{5}$$
$$\theta = \tan^{-1}(2)$$
$$Z_n=\sqrt{5}^n(\cos(n(\tan^{-1}(2)))+i\sin(n(\tan^{-1}(2))))$$
$$|Z_n|=|(1+2i)^n|=|1+2i|^n=\sqrt{5}^n$$
Therefore, it is unbounded since z-mod tends towards infinity and the real and imaginary parts display oscillatory divergence.

Second, would you suggest another way of finding convergence/divergence?

Comment: Seems correct to me. $Z_n$ is rotating around the origin in a spiral-like way, and its distance to the origin increases without bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a slightly more rigorous argument using the definition of the limit. In particular, since the shortest distance between any pair of points on concentric circles lie on the same ray through the center, we have $$|Z_{n+1} - Z_n| \leq | |Z_{n+1}| - |Z_n|| = \sqrt{5}^{n+1} - \sqrt{5}^n = 5^{\frac{n}{2}}\left(\sqrt{5}-1 \right) \geq 5^{n/2}$$ so that $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} |Z_{n+1} - Z_n| = \infty$$ Then you can apply the triangle inequality to show that for any complex number $L$, the maximum distance between $L$ and either $Z_n$ or $Z_{n+1}$ is at least $\frac{1}{2}5^{n/2}$, and thus $|Z_n - L|$ cannot be made arbitrarily small for all sufficiently large $n$. Thus the limit does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Since $(1+2i)$ is solution of $z^2-2z+5=0$ then $Z$ verifies the recurrence relation $$Z_{n+2}-2Z_{n+1}+5Z_n=0$$

If $Z_n$ was convergent to a limit $\ell$ then $\ell$ would also need to be solution of the characteristic equation.

However, neither $\ell=1+2i$ nor $\ell=1-2i$ are stable by multiplication with itself, so it cannot be a limit.